# MySQL - Finding the smallest value that is not zero

Tags: mysql

Sample table

```
----------------------------------------
Fruit           Store1           Store2
Apple             5                 6
Banana            10                4
Oranges           1                 1
Avocado           2                 1
----------------------------------------
```

Apparently, `SELECT MIN(NULLIF(Store1, 0)) FROM table` only gets the value and not the row where it is contained. I also need to compare between the two stores and get the store name.

This is my target output per queue of an item

```
----------------------------
Fruit      Lowest     Source
Apple        5        Store1
----------------------------

----------------------------
Fruit      Lowest     Source
Banana       4        Store2
----------------------------

----------------------------
Fruit      Lowest     Source
Oranges      1        Store1
----------------------------

----------------------------
Fruit      Lowest     Source
Avocado      1        Store2
----------------------------
```

Comment: What if there's a store3?

Comment: same case. compare which will be the lowest value between the stores

Comment: In that case, I strongly suggest you revise your schema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should consider Normalizing your table structure. If you plan to have more Store(s) in the table, adding a new column per store will make everything cumbersome.

Rather, you can have just three columns, *viz*, `fruit`, `store_no`, `quantity`. There are more possibilities, like having separate Master tables for `fruit` and `store` separately. In simplistic form, you can consider something like below:

```
Create Table fruits (fruit varchar(32), 
                     store_no varchar(16), 
                     quantity int);
Insert Into fruits 
Values 
('Apple', 'Store1', 5), 
('Apple', 'Store2', 6), 
('Banana', 'Store1', 10), 
('Banana', 'Store2', 4), 
('Oranges', 'Store1', 1), 
('Oranges', 'Store2', 1), 
('Avocado', 'Store1', 2), 
('Avocado', 'Store2', 1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM fruits;

| fruit   | store_no | quantity |
| ------- | -------- | -------- |
| Apple   | Store1   | 5        |
| Apple   | Store2   | 6        |
| Banana  | Store1   | 10       |
| Banana  | Store2   | 4        |
| Oranges | Store1   | 1        |
| Oranges | Store2   | 1        |
| Avocado | Store1   | 2        |
| Avocado | Store2   | 1        |
```

---

**Query #2 (To get the required output format)**

```
SELECT 
  f.fruit, 
  MIN(f.quantity) AS lowest, 
  MIN(f.store_no) AS `source`
FROM fruits AS f 
JOIN 
( SELECT fruit, 
         MIN(quantity) AS lowest 
  FROM fruits 
  WHERE quantity > 0 
  GROUP BY fruit 
) AS dt ON dt.fruit = f.fruit AND 
           dt.lowest = f.quantity 
GROUP BY f.fruit;

| fruit   | lowest | source |
| ------- | ------ | ------ |
| Apple   | 5      | Store1 |
| Avocado | 1      | Store2 |
| Banana  | 4      | Store2 |
| Oranges | 1      | Store1 |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iUQ2qFZ4oTGuDuUcT9AnoW/0)

---

**Previous Solution:**
In case of existing structure, with two columns, *viz*, `Store1` and `Store2` only, you can use Conditional comparison functions, such as [`Case .. When`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).

Always remember that [`Min()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) function is used to find minimum value out of different **row** values in a column. Here, you are trying to find minimum value out of multiple column(s).

```
SELECT 
  Fruit, 
  (
   CASE WHEN Store1 < Store2 AND Store1 > 0 THEN Store1
        ELSE Store2 
   END
  ) AS Lowest, 
  (
   CASE WHEN Store1 < Store2 AND Store1 > 0 THEN 'Store1'
        WHEN Store2 > 0 THEN 'Store2' 
        ELSE 'N/A' 
   END
  ) AS Source
FROM your_table
```

Comment: but then, there can be a case when a price is valued 0 and I'm looking for the next value that isn't 0

Comment: @Kyle what if both of them are 0 ?

Comment: Lowest value is 0, with store can be set to null or "N/A"

Comment: copy that. then what if I added store3 for future expansions of the table? how'd it perform?

Comment: @Kyle more the number of columns, it will keep on getting complex. As @Strawberry suggested, you should consider denormalizing it. You could rather store it as (`Fruit`, `Store_id`, `Value`)